# Java mail sending error?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, netbeans-7

I developed a sample mail program in Java. While sending mail, it throws exception like "553 from address not verified". How do I resolve?

Comment: Add some code if you want us to help. Can't really tell what the problem is with the info you provided

Comment: My stack trace Failed to send the mail 553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified**

Means that sender address needs to be verified (enabled) in account's configuration. Can be experienced with for example Yahoo! free accounts.

refer http://javakiss.blogspot.in/2010/10/smtp-in-java-with-javaxmail.html

It willplease to help if you provide some code.