# Send a mail using javax.mail through yahoo in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail using mail.smtp.yahoo.com in java

Here is my code for sending a mail :

```
    final String Username = "*****************";
    final String Password = "*****************";
    String to = "*****************";
    String host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    // Setup mail server
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", Username);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", Password);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Username));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText("This is actual message");

        // Send message
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, Username, Password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting this error :

```
avax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at MailHelper.main(MailHelper.java:51)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:503)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:234)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
    ... 4 more
```

I tried to send it using port 25,465 also but to no avail.
 I also tried to send it using smtp.gmail.com and gmail userid and pass but getting different errors.

Please Help

Comment: I think you are missing   `properties.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true"); `

Comment: Tried that . But getting same error.
I have created Java application and running this application locally .DO I need  to add any configuration for that ?@HelpingHands

Comment: Do you have any firewall or something installed?

Comment: PC Is in company domain so Yes @HelpingHands

Comment: Did you try the code without manually setting the port?

Comment: @RushikeshKhamborkar - then that firewall is only cause of this error. If you pass your company host , email and port then I am sure that it will work.

Comment: The port has nothing to do with a local domain firewall, it is trying to connect to a port on the smtp server, which is why I suggest removing the manual port request altogether. I've never seen anyone manually set the port in `javax.mail` before and I certainly don't know how these companies manage server requests. Maybe with super complex dynamic port forwarding?

Comment: I tried without specifying port and 
adding properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
but now I am getting this error :


com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
 at MailHelper.main(MailHelper.java:54)

Comment: @RushikeshKhamborkar - Did you try as I said?

Comment: @HelpingHands

Yes .I am getting this error :

Unknown SMTP host: ***************;

Comment: What host you tried?

Comment: mail server my company is using

Comment: I'll consider my comment as having solved your error, as you are now experiencing a new error unrelated to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990421/java-mail-sending-error

Answer (score 1):

try adding below property:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable","true");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

public class SendMail {

```
String host, port, emailid,username, password;
Properties props = System.getProperties();
Session l_session = null;

public SendMail() {
    host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    port = "587";
    emailid = "a@yahoo.com";
    username = "a";
    password = "pwd";

    emailSettings();
    createSession();
    sendMessage("test@yahoo.com", "test@gmail.com","Test","test Mail");
}

public void emailSettings() {
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
}

public void createSession() {

    l_session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });



}

public boolean sendMessage(String emailFromUser, String toEmail, String subject, String msg) {
    //System.out.println("Inside sendMessage 2 :: >> ");
    try {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(l_session);
        emailid = emailFromUser;


        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.emailid));

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(AppConstants.fromEmail));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(msg, "text/html");


        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Message Sent");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch block
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: tried it still not working. Same error: 553 From address not verified - see help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

Answer (score 0):

Use these settings

```
SMTP SERVER : smtp.mail.yahoo.com
PORT Number : 465
```

Comment: with port 465 Below error is coming :
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
 at MailHelper.main(MailHelper.java:53) @Ankit Pandey

Comment: host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        port = "587";
        emailid = "a@yahoo.com";
        username = "a";
        password = "pwd";

        emailSettings();
        createSession();
        sendMessage("a@yahoo.com", "rahul@gmail.com","Test","test Mail");

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");`
You are using 587 as port number that is used for TLS connection.

Comment: tried it still not working.

Same error: 
553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

Comment: you tried changing both port ? i mean making both 'mail.smtp.socketFactory.port' and 'mail.smtp.port' to 465